# OutOfMemoryException when building Silverlight application using CRM2011 OData Service Reference

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm, out-of-memory, dynamics-crm-2011

Following the instructions supplied with the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK CrmODataSilverlight sample code I have downloaded the OrganizationData.csdl from my CRM2011 solution and readded my service reference with it.  The csdl file is 4.8mb and has generated a Reference.cs in my solution of 13.4mb.

When I attempt to build my solution I get an error stating 'Source file '...\Reference.cs' could not be opened ('Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.')

I have restarted my machine and attempted to rebuild however I get the same issue.

What approach can I take to allow my Silverlight application to build with this service reference?  Can I get a cut down version of the csdl from CRM2011 containing just the entities I am interested in or is there another approach I can take?  I don't fancy having to manually edit the csdl file as it makes maintenance a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article about filtering out items when generating a proxy from crm 2011.
Probably not exactly what you need for silverlight but hopefully points you in the right direction.

http://erikpool.blogspot.com/2011/03/filtering-generated-entities-with.html

As for the out of memory, you can try to increase your virtual memory amount in windows.

Comment: Brilliant - I'm actually working with the standard XRM interface currently and this is a massive help - I always wondered how anyone managed to work with the early bound entities!